# Accidentally formatted WINRE_DRV

Tags: windows-8.1, formatting

I'm on a Lenovo (Windows 8.1) and I was trying to format an external HDD I couldn't read, through console command "diskpart", but I did `format fs=NTFS` on WINRE_DRV by mistake. The computer still runs of course but there could be consequences? What is that partition for? Is it essential? I've tried to look for an answer on the Internet but responses goes from "nothing will happen" to "your computer will not boot again" so I'd like more infos to understand if I have to make a backup right now or if I can solve it with drivers or other (or even if the formatting returned a fake positive result and that part of disk can't be formatted).

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1046857/what-are-pbr-drv-and-winre-drv-drives-for

Answer (score 0):

As written in the following link, that WINRE_DRV partition is for the first installation for Windows.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/hard-drives-and-partitions

You might be able to create a bootable image disk, depending on the lenovo notebook type.
Many Lenovo Notebooks have a hidden partition to recover the system to it`s factory state with the Lenovo Onekey Recovery. This will reset all partitions to the state when first bought.